# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' -- @tf.contrib.eager.defun

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have problem connected tensorflow, In my script has decoder @tf.contrib.eager.defun. After running gave only error (AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'). Please help me. My version tensor = 2.8.0[image]

I change some tensorflow command but again this problem

Comment: `tf.contrib` has moved out of TF starting TF 2.0, take a look at these tf 2.0 [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha0). For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrate_tf2). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@tf.contrib.eager.defun` appears to do some sort of pre-compilation of its decorated function to improve performance and is a TF 1.x method. I couldn't find where it was moved in TF 2.0, so I got it to work by either downgrading TF or removing the decorator (the latter slows down execution speed).